# Выбрать количество записей с одним параметром

Tags: mysql

таблица

```
id | os
-------
1  | 1
-------
2  | 1
-------
3  | 2
-------
4  | 1
-------
4  | 3
```

Нужно выбрать количество строк с os 1 и os 2. Проблема в том, что в столбце os могут быть разные значения - 1,2,8,10 и др.

на выводе должно быть так:

```
os | count
-------
1  | 3
-------
2  | 1
-------
3  | 1
```

Запрос ниже неверный, как поступить?

```
SELECT os, COUNT( DISTINCT os ) AS count FROM table
```

Comment: Я не специалист, но нельзя Select os, count(*) as count from table group by os ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну вроде вот так, если я правильно понял задачу:

```
SELECT `os`, COUNT(*) as `count` FROM `tablename` WHERE `os` IN (1,2) GROUP BY `os`
```

Ну или для всех записей:

```
SELECT `os`, COUNT(*) as `count` FROM `tablename` GROUP BY `os`
```